# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } doctype

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, batch-file

I am writing again on a little import script which I have to split because of the data amount.

So I have a start.php with the fancy ajax action and the dbactions.php doing all the hard work.

The script first initializes the data, checks for doubles and creates a session with ids.

Then it should go through the ids in batches.

On first call the start.php has no errors, and the first part of the script runs well, in creates the user session with an array over 12k ids.

But when I output the result of the second initialize, it gives the the error message of

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }**

See screenshot attached:

[image]

The dbactions.php itself gives no error despite the missing $do variable, and the start.php at first load also not.

The start.php looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
session_start();
$_SESSION['start_counter'] = 0;
$_SESSION['batches'] = 1;
$_SESSION['array_counter'] = 0;
$_SESSION['batchcount'] = 0;
$_SESSION['newsletter'] = 0;


?>

    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>DB-actions</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
            function DoSomething(what){
                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "dbactions.php?do=" + what,
                    type: "GET",            
                    dataType: "html"
                });
                $('#godosomething').attr('disabled','true');
                $('#doing').show();
                $('#callmsg').empty();
                $('body').addClass('grey');
                request.done(function(msg) {
                    $('#doing').hide();
                    $("body").removeClass("grey");
                    $("#callmsg").html(msg);          
                });
                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            padding, margin: 0;
            body  { padding:20px 0;}
            p { padding-bottom:3px;}
            #callmsg { margin:50px 0; }
            #insertmsg { margin:50px 0; }
            #doing { display:none; position:absolute; bottom:48%; right:48%; border: 1px solid green; padding: 20px; background-color:green; color: white;}
            .grey { background-color: grey; opacity: 0.5;}
            .green { color:green; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>Start the import</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="DoSomething('initialize')" id="godosomething">Go baby</button>
    <div id="callmsg"></div>
    <div id="doing">I am working, please wait...</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I know there are several threads about it, the suggestions where, that the charset is wrong (not as excepted from ajax), but I have this on each file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And there was a suggestion about the ' and the " marks, I tried to change them in the output, but it did not help.

I thought also of the long output of the print_r, but disabling it didn't help.

This is the second output:

```
echo '<h2>Batch successfull</h2>';
$_SESSION['start_counter'] = $_SESSION['start_counter'] + $numberofqueries;
$_SESSION['batches']++;
echo "<p>Next? <button type='button' onclick" . "='DoSomething('makearray')" ."id='godosomething'>Go baby</button></p>";
echo '<p>Batch'.$_SESSION['batches'].' from '.$_SESSION['batchcount'].'</p>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION['users']);
echo '</pre>';
```

**ADDITIONAL EDIT**

I uncommented the whole second output until the h2 echo, and it still give me the same error.

How can this be? So the error comes not from the second output?

Comment: You have an unexpected `}` in start.php on line 2?

Comment: No, I am not, the error is caused by something else

Comment: Maybe change the order of `session_start();` and `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` I think you need to `session_start` before sending output to the header

Comment: Thanks I tried it, but it did not help

Comment: BTW I use Chrome, too but sometimes Firefox's Firebug gives more detailed info and exactly where the error is in the code.

Comment: Thank you Pjack, this is strange, firebug did not give me error message at all (still not working in ff) but I am not use to it, so maybe I did not look right?

Comment: @Pjack I have added a live script, (edited the question) if you have any clue where it could be, thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change This -

```
echo "<p>Next? <button type='button' onclick" . "='DoSomething('makearray')" ."id='godosomething'>Go baby</button></p>";
```

To-

```
echo "<p>Next? <button type='button' onclick=DoSomething('makearray') id='godosomething'>Go baby</button></p>";
```

And let me know if it clicks or not.

**EDIT**--

Remove any `dummy spaces/content` from your file.

Change `<!DOCTYPE>` to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Thank you. Your first line was the answer from raam86, I had it before like yours. But your answer did also not help... Should I post the complete PHP code from dbactions.php?

Comment: @Owl can u please show me the whole code and the error that is flagging in ??

Comment: Thank you @swapnes here it is: http://pastebin.com/fxNxQjW7 - the error message is like in the screenshot above

Comment: Thank you @swapnesh for your help! could you find anything where the error could be? I edited my question again

Comment: @Owl let me know if u still need help..I am here

Comment: yes of course thank you! I edited my question at the bottom, I still have no clue where the error could be. I also changed all " to ' and otherwise, did not help :(

Comment: @Owl can u plz check if no white space or dummy spaces exist in the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32319/discussion-between-swapnesh-and-owl)

Comment: thank you! This is so strange since you do not receive any error with the same code as I..

Comment: @Owl is that error still prompting at your end?? try removing any cache and let me know then

Comment: Its still the same error, cache was emptied several times, thank you!

Comment: I added a live version of the script, see question above. I double checked the script you send me, its the same with all hidden character like new line and so on with the one which is online now. Any idea?

Comment: @Owl let me know if this is what u are looking for http://i.imgur.com/5x0RJSU.jpg :)

Comment: okk ..lunch time..will catch un in an hour or ping me on chat..very simple mistake :)

Comment: I do not understand, I thought maybe the screen resize plugin from chrome making problems, because it adds into the site-sourcecode. But I tried the development page with IE (no-addons) and the same ...

Comment: wow thank you! I have breakfast time now but will be on screen later!

Comment: I am on chat now if you have time, or if you can give me the hint where the problem is, thx so much

Answer (score 1):

you are not qouting this correctly.

```
   'DoSomething('makearray')'
```

should be:

```
 "DoSomething('makearray')"
```

And in php:

```
 echo "<p>Start first? <button type='button' onclick" . "='DoSomething('makearray')" ."id='godosomething'>Go baby</button></p>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found an error in my error-description, the error msg comes from the secound output. I added it in the question and tried your answer, but it did not help. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is invalid. Try this.

```
           <style type="text/css">
                padding { margin: 0;}
                body  { padding:20px 0;}
                p { padding-bottom:3px;}
                #callmsg { margin:50px 0; }
                #insertmsg { margin:50px 0; }
                #doing { display:none; position:absolute; bottom:48%; right:48%; border: 1px solid green; padding: 20px; background-color:green; color: white;}
                .grey { background-color: grey; opacity: 0.5;}
                .green { color:green; }
            </style>
```

You have an error on your second button.

Change this

```
<button type="button" onclick="DoSomething(" makearray")"="" id="godosomething">Go baby</button>
```

To this

```
<button type="button" onclick="DoSomething('makearray')" id="godosomething">Go baby</button>
```

Comment: ohm yes thank you there was a css error, but your answer is not correct and it has nothing to do with the error, but thanks anyway

Comment: Thank you Pjack. The second button is uncommented at the moment, and the problem is still there, so it cannot be that. But I changed it anyway and tried, no change. But thank you very much!

Comment: It works when that is fixed. **Batch successfull** not sure why it doesnt for you.

Comment: you mean the test version at the development link is working for you too?

Comment: yes.. when I fix that. Where is the PHP code that has **Start First** next to the button. I don't see that posed above. That is the line with the problem